# weird situation with sql express

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have this weird problem with Sql server express (2012) where I load lots of data into memory (with entity framework), make some computations with it, then bulk insert it back into temporary table and invoke stored procedure which using merge statement writes back the results (writing is done after the data loaded in multiple non-overlapping batches). The problem starts when I launch several such computations in parallel - suddenly for about 30 seconds database becomes unreachable. All the tables and not just used in the computation give this on select:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
```

While select from management studio are ok.

Weird, like I said as if some resource is out. This is express and I can't even profile it properly. Any suggestions on how to identify the culprit are appreciated.

**Edit**
I've now discovered that sometimes situation is getting even worse with management studio not able to connect to server at all:

```
A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The wait operation timed out.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 258)
```

**Edit2** Ok the culprit is 1Gb memory limitation in express. I'm frustrated with that, seriously, 1Gb? I wander why not to just use plane files or something?

Comment: Are the calls you're making computationally expensive? Would there be any improvement if the bulk writes were segmented? Even though your request times out, are you able to verify whether they succeed?

Comment: @AlexT.You mean calls to the database? Well the merge statement is computationally expensive and I can see one core almost completely taken (express can only use one core). Bulk inserts are already segmented and they do succeed eventually. Timed out requests do not succeed.

Comment: I'm wondering whether there might be some issues with shared resource synchronization... Do you think there could be some contention?

Comment: @AlexT. I wonder how would I verify that. Almost sure it's the merge statement doing something bad with locks

Comment: Haha, yeah that's the thing. Maybe search for circular dependencies; determine whether it were at all possible for two concurrent tasks to wait upon the successful completion of one another. Maybe you could confirm this by sending trivially small amounts of data using the same approach and seeing whether it causes the server to hang.

Comment: You know about the hardware resource limitations enforced in SQL Server Express, right? Like 1GB of memory, 1 CPU, etc. You can only do so many things in parallel until you start exhausting those resources.

Comment: Also, about `MERGE`, [please read this in full](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/).

Comment: @AaronBertrand I know that there are limitations, I just wonder which one I've hit here.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Wait, express can't use more than 1Gb ram? Lol. That probably is that. I'd accept that as answer.